# How to return JSON null result from a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following action:

```
    [Route("GetNull")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetNull()
    {
        object value = new { Name = "John" };
        return Ok(value);
    }
```

It returns the serialized object:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2018 06:13:05 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 22

{
  "name": "John"
}
```

If the object is set to null like this:

```
    [Route("GetNull")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetNull()
    {
        object value = null;
        return Ok(value);
    }
```

I would expect null in JSON to be returned. However, I get empty content like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2018 06:17:37 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 0
```

I do I get the controller to serialize null into json and return:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2018 06:13:05 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 4

null
```

Comment: Why do you want this

Comment: `return Json(null)`

Comment: return Json(value ?? "null");

Comment: `return Json(null)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET Core has a specific output formatter that returns the `204 - NoContent` response when you try to return null. To allow you to return null and get a 200 response you can remove the default formatter for NoContent.

In `startup.cs`:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();
});
```

This will allow you to do the following and get a `200 OK` response:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetNull()
{
    object value = null;
    return Ok(value);
}
```

You must note that ASP.NET will always try to format the response as JSON as that is the default response format. So the response header will look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2018 12:36:33 GMT
```

The important thing is the status code is now `200`.

The Microsoft documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.1#special-case-formatters)

Answer (score 0):

As documented by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-5.0), you can return a null JsonResult from your controller.

For example,

```
return Json(null);
```

However a better approach might be to return an OK status, if that is all you need.

```
return Ok();
```